# Как исправить позиционирование background-image в Opera?

Tags: css, вёрстка, opera, кроссбраузерность

Приветствую мастера-верстальщики!

При верстке шапки [сайта](http://lightoption.com.ua/temp/kazantip/) и использовании картинки в качестве бекграунда для меню, столкнулся с проблемой, что в браузере `Opera`, бекграунд немного смещается относительно остальных элементов. Параментры картинки совпадают с меню:

[image: Пример глюка]

Эксперименты с отступами (`margin`, `padding`) положительный результат не принесли. Все что знал, испробовал.

Был ли у вас опыт решения подобной проблемы? Что вы можете порекомендовать?

Comment: в какой версии оперы наблюдается подобная проблема?

Comment: Очеведно что проблема в позиционировании. `margin` и `padding` не действуют на фон по понятным причинам. В какой версии глючит? В последней, в какой я работаю, всё нормально.

Comment: Стоит последняя версия Opera 28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И в старой и в новой версии оперы у меня все нормально отображается.
Может-быть у вас банально включен зум страницы? Сбросьте его.
Сделать это можно сочетанием клавиш `сtrl + 0`.
Если его включить, то проявляется баг очень похожий на ваш.

[image: Без масштабирования]

Насчет вашей верстки: она довольно странная в целом. Зачем вы разделяете фоновую картинку на маленькие блоки, если можно сделать ее целиком.

Comment: Просто верстаю из того что есть. У меня сейчас нет исходного макета, а только файлы старой верстки. Версия браузера Opera 28 http://prntscr.com/6o4luv, смещение есть. Сделайте скрин в вашем браузере пожалуйста.

Comment: Я добавил в ответ скриншот из Opera 28 с отключенным масштабированием и инструкцию по отключению эффекта масштабирования. Ваш баг воспроизводится при масштабе 125% во всех браузерах с движком на вебките.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! У меня зум 100%. Но проверил на стационарном компьютере, все в порядке. Возможно это зависит от формата монитора (у меня 16:9, на стационарном стандартный 4:3). Поэтому оставим как есть.